# Detect potential segment intersections in NumPy (boolean)

Tags: python, numpy, vector, coordinates, intersection

I have two numpy arrays consisting of several line segments with the format `[x1, y1, x2, y2]`:

```py
foo = np.array([
    [2, 3, 2, 1],
    [6, 3, 5, 4],
    [5, 6, 8, 2],
    [5, 2, 6, 5]
])

bar = np.array([
    [4, 2, 7, 8],
    [2, 1, 6, 9]
])
```

My ultimate goal is to check every segment from `foo` against every segment from `bar` and verify intersections. No need for the intersection point, I just want to know if two segment intersect (True/False).

In reality there are a few billion lines in `foo` and a few hundred lines in `bar` so I thought I would perform a prior, simpler check that verifies the following, before jumping to a more thourough method:

```py
# two segments are potentially intersecting if and only if
xFmin <= xBmax && xBmin <= xFmax     # x overlap
&&
yFmin <= yBmax && yBmin <= yFmax     # y overlap
```

The idea is that if two line segments don't satisfy this test together, then there is no way they intersect. I'm trying to implement this test with numpy but with little luck so far. A few questions come to mind:

- how to determine e.g. `yFmin` and `yFmax` (can be done once by pre-ordering coordinates)
- how to correctly slice and broadcast the two arrays to make the comparisons mentioned above
- is it possible to make the whole comparison in only one operation for all the segments?

This test should give a final output similar to the below:

```py
result = np.array([
    [True, False, False, True],   # all segments in Foo against the first segment in Bar
    [False, False, True, True]    # all segments in Foo against the second segment in Bar
])
```

Comment: How you check intersection by dot product? Because just dot product should be comparable in speed or faster than all this checkings.

Comment: I'm not sure than an operation involving trigonometry would be as fast as a few arithmetic comparisons, but it might be worth a try — I've updated my comparisons by the way, having checked what seems to be the most efficient way to test if two ranges overlap, and testing that both for X and for Y axis

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago, I solved a similar problem implementing the sweep-line algorithm described in:

> Michael Shamos, Dan Hoey (1976). Geometric  Intersection Problems.
>   https://doi.org/10.1109/SFCS.1976.16

It converts the problem from O(N²) into O(N log N).

**Added after Jivan's comment:**

For the comparisons of segments from a set against segments in a second set you could try this method:

> Chan (1994), A Simple Trapezoid Sweep Algorithm for Reporting Red/Blue Segment Intersections. https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.44.4227

Disclaimer: I haven't implemented this one.

Comment: hey @aerobiomat, thanks for this, that's really nice — although for this particular example, I don't want to compute all possible intersections between all N segments in a plane — I have two groups of segments N and M and only need to compute every N segment against every M segment, so the solution described here would not apply — but again, really helpful to know anyway

Comment: The number of intersecion can be M*N. Imagine M vertical and N horizontal lines forming a regular grid. How M*N crossing be found in less that O(MN) time?

Comment: Chan's algorithm runs in O(n log n + k) time where n = M+N and k is the number of crossings. So, in the MN crossing case, it would be O((M+N) log(M+N) + MN).

Answer (score 0):

If you have billions of segments, I would suggest using a library, like this: https://github.com/Permafacture/python-computational-geometry, which allows you to batch the computations.

Comment: I’m using numpy in this question but in reality I’m using CuPy which has similar syntax but runs on GPU

Answer (score 0):

For the first question I would suggest to just loop through all your segments and order the entries by comparing the two X extrema and the two Y extrema setting the segment representation to something like

```
[x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max]
```

(This representation should reduce the number of operations you need to do on each segment, at most two swaps)
and you store the result.

Then you can loop through the segments in bar (should be more efficient because there are less of them) and use your filtering condition. You can write the condition per column, so the first one will be

```
x_min_bools = foo[:,0] <= x_bar_min
```

And you do in a similarly way the others three. Then you can use np.logical_and() to combine arrays of bools getting the row for results.